# string.gmatch to find a string included between two inequality signs

Tags: string, lua, expression

I'm using Lua, already used Google and nothing, can't find way to get string between inequality signs (< >). Other brackets are easy to get but these not. It's possible to do?

Target: How to grab "name" from string between inequality signs?

String: < name >: Message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `name` does not contain `>`, then `<(.-)>` works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `(%b<>)` pattern to capture matching `<>`. Then using that value, you can simply use `string.sub` to cut off the first and last char:

```
name,message=('< name<> > : Foo Bar!'):match('(%b<>)%s*:%s*(.*)')
name=name:sub(2,-2)
print(name,'sent message :',message)
```

As you can see this also takes care of strings containing other, embedded `<>` signs

Comment: Can't do something like `pattern = "<(.*)>: (.*)"`? Then `for name, message in string.gmatch(text, pattern) do`

Comment: you can add whatever you wish to the pattern I gave. I updated my answer to also match the message.